# Getting debug value in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Something that's bugging me for quite a while now...

I have to debug a lot of code that's not from me in Visual Studio and often I find functions like this:

```
Public Function DoSomething() As Object
    ...
    Return Me.DoSomethingElse()
End Function
```

When debugging I like to move the mouse over a variable to see their content.

Is there any way to see the result of `Me.DoSomethingElse()` without leaving the function `DoSomething` and without stepping in `Me.DoSomethingElse()` (I might not have the source code of `Me.DoSomethingElse()` to step into). Something like moving the mouse over the `Return` (that's not working).

I don't like to change the code and put the result of `Me.DoSomethingElse()` in a temporary variable just to be able to inspect it, and I don't like to run `Me.DoSomethingelse()` in the Immediate Window either because that might change data I don't like to change twice.

Comment: What about adding `Me.DoSomethingElse()` in `Watch` window?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same like running it in the Immediate Window? It is getting executed and may throw an error when moving on in the debugging because it is executed a second time.

Comment: what if you add `, nse` to the expression to avoid side effects?

Comment: I didn't know about this `No Side Effects` flag for the Watch and Immediate Window, I'll give it a try.